# Why the concurrent performance of my server(ASP .net core + MySQL) is very low? something wrong in my .net code?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I used asp.net core and MySQL.  the connector I used is connector/net. I use apache bench to test， request per second is only 4.06

Is this normal? I use java spring to test, the requests per second is 1000+ ...

I just want to know is it because of something wrong in my code?

Comment: here is my code :

Comment: using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
            {
               conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT film_id,title FROM film", conn);

Comment: does it miss connection polling